# Triggering animations to start once slide is active/showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like some CSS3 or JQuery animations to start only once the specific slide is showing in my slider. Its not the animating i need help with, its more figuring out how to trigger/start the animation only once the slide/parent container fades in.

Here is the JQuery for the slider i'm currently using.

JQuery:

```
var triggers = $('ul.triggers li');
var images = $('ul.images li');
var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
var target;

triggers.first().addClass('active');
images.hide().first().show();

function sliderResponse(target) {
images.fadeOut(800).eq(target).fadeIn(800);
triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
}

triggers.click(function() {
if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
    target = $(this).index();
    sliderResponse(target);
    resetTiming();
}
});

$('.next').click(function() {
target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
sliderResponse(target);
resetTiming();
});
$('.prev').click(function() {
target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
lastElem = triggers.length-1;
target === 0 ? target = lastElem : target = target-1;
sliderResponse(target);
resetTiming();
});

function sliderTiming() {
target = $('ul.triggers li.active').index();
target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
sliderResponse(target);
}

var timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },7000);
function resetTiming() {
clearInterval(timingRun);
timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },7000);
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="mask">
      <ul class="images">
    <li>
      <h1>eCommerce Websites</h1>
      <h2>profit from effective, beautiful and functional eCommerce websites that work.</h2>
      <a class="button" href="contact.html">FURTHER DETAILS</a>
      <a href="#">view portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">get in touch</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Responsive Websites</h1>
      <h2>making your website mobile friendly is now more important than ever before. Lets build a user friendly website ideal for mobile devices.</h2>
      <a class="button" href="contact.html">FURTHER DETAILS</a>
      <a href="#">view portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">get in touch</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Literature Design</h1>
      <h2>Literature design that is clear, precise and reflects your brand. Make a good impression with effective literature.</h2>
      <a class="button" href="contact.html">FURTHER DETAILS</a>
      <a href="#">view portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">get in touch</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Design Packages</h1>
      <h2>Benefit from my money saving packages that offer a variety of popular services all in one bundle!</h2>
      <a class="button" id="packagesbtn">FURTHER DETAILS</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="triggers">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
<span class="control prev"></span>
<span class="control next"></span>
```

It is the h1 and h2 elements i would like to animate when the slide fades in.

Thanks for your help.

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fadeIn()` accepts a callback. When specified, it will be triggered right after the element stops fading in (the animation completes). Example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="js-fadein one"></div>
<div class="js-callback-element two"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.js-fadein').fadeIn(1000, function() {
    /// Show div .two after div .one is faded in
    $('.js-callback-element').fadeIn();
});
```

The anonymous function used in the first `fadein()` is the callback.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/my7a5a0n/

Think that's enough for you to figure out the rest.